# Uploading multipart file with Apache Camel 4.0.0 and Spring Security 6.1.2

Tags: spring-security, apache-camel

I have a simple Camel flow where LogProcessor is just a mock processor that checks the size of uploaded file.

```
...

  <!-- embed Camel with routes -->
  <camelContext id="SampleCamel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <jmxAgent id="agent" disabled="true"/>
    <rest path="/upload" bindingMode="off">
      <post>
        <to uri="direct:start-6283a0f8afb73831dfc79a55"/>
      </post>
    </rest>
    <route id="meIf4A676g" streamCache="true" >
      <from uri="direct:start-6283a0f8afb73831dfc79a55"/>
      <process ref="logProcessor"/>
    </route>
  </camelContext>
...
```

Application is protected with Spring Security configuration. I have configured InMemoryUserDetailsManager with simple user (Username: user, Password: pass) and SCRF is disabled.

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
    ;
    return http.build();
  }
```

When I upload a file with curl or Postman Exchange in LogProccessor doesn't have file as body.

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/camel/upload' \
                    --header 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz' \
                    --form 'file=@"/path/examples.yaml"'
```

When I downgrade Apache Camel to 3.20.4 and Spring Security to 5.7.8 (Spring Boot 2.7.1) everything works as expected.

I have created github repo https://github.com/McNullty/camel-upload-with-security with working example, on master branch is  version with latest Spring Security and Apache Camel and on old-spring-boot branch is a version with older Spring Security and Apache Camel that works as expected.

Comment: I have found workaround.  If I add `.requestCache(RequestCacheConfigurer::disable)` to security configuration, application works as expected. 

I have also found that if I put log statement that "tickles" `request.getInputStream()` in filter before RequestCacheAwareFilter application also works as expected.